# How to check if a String is an Int in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a TextField which I want to verify if the inputted text is an integer. How could I do this?

I want to write a function like this:

```
func isStringAnInt(string: String) -> Bool {

}
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

### String Extension & Computed Property

You can also add to `String` a computed property.

> The logic inside the computed property is the same described by *OOPer*

```
extension String {
    var isInt: Bool {
        return Int(self) != nil
    }
}
```

### Now you can

```
"1".isInt // true
"Hello world".isInt // false
"".isInt // false
```

Comment: This is imho swiftier than the accepted answer and thus should be accepted.

Comment: yep. Cleanest answer

Comment: That solution was not working for me but the extension with the regular expression worked: https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-check-if-string-is-number-in-swift/

Answer (score 27):

Use this function

```
func isStringAnInt(string: String) -> Bool {
    return Int(string) != nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check like this

```
func isStringAnInt(stringNumber: String) -> Bool {

    if let _ = Int(stringNumber) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

OR

you can create an extension for String. Go to File -> New File -> Swift File

And in your newly created Swift file you can write

```
extension String
{
    func isStringAnInt() -> Bool {

        if let _ = Int(self) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

In this way you will be able to access this function in your whole project like this

```
var str = "123"
if str.isStringAnInt() // will return true
{
 // Do something
}
```

Comment: @EricD Please edit my answer if there is something wrong so that I can learn as well.

Comment: Did a little editing.  You might want to make `isStringAnInt()` a computed property `extension String { var isInt: Bool { if let _ = Int(self) { return true } return false } }`, then you can do `"123".isInt`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use following extension method that use a different logic than all mentioned answers

```
extension String  {
    var isStringAnInt: Bool {
        return !isEmpty && self.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted) == nil
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
if s is String {
  print("Yes, it's a String")
} else if s is Int {
  print("It is Integer")
} else {
  //some other check
}
```

Comment: This code returns the correct result, however the question asked for a function, and this code is not a function.